# Is this predicate valid to delete single shared_ptr's?

Tags: c++, c++11

I wrote a predicate used in a `remove_if` call that deletes shared_ptr's of type StemmedSentence from an vector of sentences.

The predicate:

```
class EraseSentenceIf {
    ArrayStemmedSnippet * m_ass;

public:
    EraseSentenceIf(ArrayStemmedSnippet *ass)
    : m_ass(ass) {
    }

    bool operator()(const std::shared_ptr<
        ArrayStemmedSnippet::StemmedSentence>& s) {
        std::shared_ptr<ArrayStemmedSnippet::StemmedSentence> tmp = s;

        // --- set StemmedSentnce object in ArrayStemmedSnippet class
        s->setParent(m_ass);

        // --- if true delete this sentence)
        if (s->trimStopWords()) {
            tmp.reset();

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
};
```

The remove_if call:

```
EraseSentenceIf esi(this);
sentences.erase(
    std::remove_if(
        sentences.begin(), sentences.end(), esi),
    sentences.end()
);
```

Declaration:

```
std::vector<shared_ptr<StemmedSentence> > sentences;
```

The construction of the sentences objects looks like this:

```
sentences.push_back(shared_ptr<StemmedSentence>(
    new StemmedSentence(index, i - 1 )));
```

The code seems to run fine, valgrind / gdb does not moan. I just want to get sure that I handle  the deletion (or release) of the shared_ptr in a correct way. Can somebody please confirm this? Maybe I can improve something or I overlooked an important point. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: `tmp.reset();` only resets `tmp`, not the object inside of `sentences`.

Comment: @ildjarn: Because it was copied, incremented the reference counter and this is why I only delete `tmp` ?! I can not use `s` because the compiler says `error: ‘class ArrayStemmedSnippet::StemmedSentence’ has no member named ‘reset’`, which I understand. So how do I clearly delete it?

Comment: Just a side note: If you make your `operator()` `const`, you could pass your `EraseSentenceIf` object as temporary instead of using the `esi` variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Within the predicate you make a copy of the `shared_ptr` hence incrementing the reference count:

```
    std::shared_ptr<ArrayStemmedSnippet::StemmedSentence> tmp = s;
```

A few lines later you explicitly reset *this copy* (note that this does not release any memory unless it's the last living `shared_ptr` referring to the pointee):

```
    // --- if true delete this sentence)
    if (s->trimStopWords()) {
        // NOT NECESSARY -- reference count will be decremented when tmp falls out of scope
        tmp.reset();

        return true;
    }
```

The actual deletion occurs when the `shared_ptr` residing inside the `vector` is destroyed (assuming it's the last remaining copy):

```
sentences.erase(
    std::remove_if(
        sentences.begin(), sentences.end(), esi),
    sentences.end()
);
```

So, everything will work fine as it is but the `tmp` variable in the predicate is unnecessary.

Comment: OK, I got it now. Means by simply returning `true` to `remove_if` tells `erase_if` to actually delete the pointer from the vector, right? Because I see that the destructor of the `StemmedSentence` object is called.

Comment: @AndreasW.Wylach Right.  Though technically, the deletion could occur during `remove_if` since it overwrites the items to be removed with those to be kept (hence causing the removed `shared_ptr`'s to be destroyed).  `erase` just removes the garbage from the end of the `vector` once `remove_if` is finished.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the suggestions! I made the changes and as I see in the allocations count of valgrind, indeed there are less allocations with this change. I basically forget that the `tmp` assignment makes a copy.

Answer (score 2):

1. The copy of the pointer is completely unnecessary: as long as the code is not sharing `shared_ptr`s among threads (which is really, really silly), taking a `shared_ptr` argument by reference ensures it lives at least until the function finishes executing.
2. Even if the copy was necessary, passing by reference to immediately make a copy is a *pessimisation* as it forbids moves. [Don't pass `shared_ptr` by reference if you're going to copy it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10826541/passing-shared-pointers-as-arguments/10826907#10826907).
3. The pointer in the vector will be destroyed by `erase`, there's no need to manually `reset` anything.
4. A predicate that mutates its argument is bound to raise eyebrows. Depending on the semantics of `setParent` it may or may not be problematic, but it is something I'd avoid if I could.

Comment: +1; OP seems to be having difficulties understanding the founding principles behind smart pointers. I would suggest understanding the problem before taking up the buzzword solution. There are a lot of online resources, just a quick search on SO reveals many useful answers that successfully FAQ-ify the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/395123/raii-and-smart-pointers-in-c/395519#395519

Comment: StemmedSentence is an nested class of ArrayStemmedSnippet and needs to point to the current ArrayStemmedSnippet object. I think there is no problem with that.

Comment: @Domagoj Pandža: Thank you for your kind suggestion. I am doing that already while I try something out (learning by doing), and I ask here if I am on the right track. Yes, smart pointers are new to me. So forgive me for my beginners mistakes.